# WebBrowser for PDF going gray after some seconds

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, webbrowser-control

I had a WebBrowser in my app and it was working well.
Now all of a sudden the behaviour is that after some seconds it goes gray.

[image]

The code is extremely simple:

```
try
{
    var wbb = new WebBrowser() { };
    wbb.Loaded += (s, e) =>
    {
        wbb.Navigate(new Uri(@"C:\temp\a.pdf"));
    };      
    grdMain.Children.Add(wbb);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

I had to put the try catch just to see if any exception was fired.
This doesn't happen with

```
wbb.Navigate(new Uri(@"https://www.google.com/"));
```

I tried several hints (fixed size, IsEnabled=true,... ) but none worked.
I also search for an event firing that was spoiling the view but couldn't find it.
I would not go for WebView2 for it needs some distributable which could not be present at the customer.
Thank you for any help

Patrick

Comment: I guess you have suggested the solution. The problem might be the antivirus!! As for your question 1. the pdf is loaded, 2. the pdf is grayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem is related with my Internet Explorer. Trying the same program on another computer showed that the problem is only on my pc.

That being said when launching Internet Explorer I am shown a message which says that this browser will be discontinued from June the 22nd 2022. Does this mean that also the Webview will not work anymore?